# Meager set and $\mathrm{MA}$

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

**Martin's axiom**. Let $\langle\mathbb P,\leq\rangle$ be a ccc partially ordered set. If $\mathcal D$ is a family of dense subset of $\mathbb P$ such that $|\mathcal D|<\mathfrak c$, then there exists a $\mathcal D$-generic filter $F$ in $\mathbb P.$ it is usually abbreviated by $\mathrm{MA}$. The following theorem is well known.

**Theorem:** If $\mathrm{MA}$ holds then a union of less than continuum many meager subsets of $\mathbb R$ is meager in $\mathbb R$.

So, it is clear that any subset of $\mathbb R$ with cardinality less than $\mathfrak c$ is meager.

**My question is Can the theorem above be hold with a weaker set-theoretical assumption ? or we need the whole $\mathrm{MA}$ to prove it ?**

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: In section 5 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9310224.pdf) the consistency of "the union of less the continuum many meagre sets is meagre"+"MA fails in a bad way" is established. I suspect there is a much easier way to show that not MA is consistent with the union of meagre sets statement

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, Could you explain more please? I got confused since  $\text MA$  implies that "the union of less the continuum many meagre sets is meagre". In the paper , said the union of less the continuum many meagre sets is meagre+$\text MA$ fails.

Comment: @00GB You might have misinterpreted "the union of less the continuum many meagre sets is meagre+M fails" as meaning "(the union of less the continuum many meagre sets is meagre+M) fails", but in fact it means "the union of less the continuum many meagre sets is meagre+(M fails)", which answers your question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, I did not study modlel or forcing before , so I might say something makes no sense.   We know $\text MA$ implies that $\mathfrak c$ is regular. Is it true that we can build a model such that the union of less than continuum many meager sets is meager. +$\text MA$ fails implies the continuum is regular.

Comment: @00GB If every union of less than continuum meager sets is meager, then the continuum is a regular cardinal (regardless of whether MA holds). Proof: Otherwise  $\mathbb R$ would be the union of $<\mathfrak c$ sets $A_i$, each of which is has cardinality $<\mathfrak c$. Then each $A_i$ would be meager (being the union of $<\mathfrak c$ singletons) and therefore their union $\mathbb R$ would be meager.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, Thank you so much for your answer. are you using chat sometimes in case I want  ask you or do not use it ? or there is other way to contact you. In case not, I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to build a model in which MA fails but every union of $<\mathfrak c$ meager sets is meager is to start with a model of GCH and adjoin Hechler reals in a finite-support iteration of length $\aleph_2$.

A table of facts of this sort is in Section 11 of my chapter of the Handbook of Set Theory, a preprint of which is available at [http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/hbk.pdf](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eablass/hbk.pdf) .

For a lot more information about MA (and weaker forms of MA), the standard reference is David Fremlin's book, "Consequences of Martin's Axiom".